# Deleting android.hardware.location.gps.xml file to disable GPS

Tags: android, gps, android-hardware

I want to remove GPS feature from phone. What if I removed the

`system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.location.gps.xml` file,

Will it remove all `allow-gps` permission granted to all users?